# Snort could not find rule type activate

Tags: windows, snort

As snort docs say, I can use rule types Activate/Dynamic:

```
Activate/Dynamic Rules

Activate/dynamic rule pairs give Snort a powerful capability.  
You can now have one rule activate another when it's action is performed for a set number of packets.
This is very useful if you want to set Snort up to perform follow on recording when a specific rule "goes off".
Activate rules act  just like alert rules, except they have a *required* option field:  "activates". Dynamic rules act just like log rules, but they have a  different option field: "activated_by".
Dynamic rules have a second  required field as well, "count".  When the "activate" rule goes off, it turns on the dynamic rule it is  linked to (indicated by the activates/activated_by option numbers) for  "count" number of packets (50 in this case).
```

However, my rule leads to an error:

```
activate tcp any any -> 127.0.0.1 any (flags:S; activates:1;sid:1;)
dynamic tcp any any -> 127.0.0.1 any (flags:R; sid:2; activated_by: 1; count:1; msg: "NMAP OS Scan";)
```

```
Initializing rule chains...
ERROR: c:\snort\rules\nmap.rules(1) Unknown rule type: activate.
Fatal Error, Quitting..
```

Snort version 2.9.17-WIN32 GRE (Build 199)
OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

According to [official documentation](https://www.snort.org/documents#OfficialDocumentation) activate/dynamic rules are phased out in favor of a combination of ***tagging*** and ***flowbits***.

1. **flowbits (Section 3.6.10 of User Manual)** allows you filtering traffic (in most cases - TCP) at the Session preprocessing stage (for more details on this type of preprocessor, see section 2.2.2 of the user manual). Thus, it can filter packets with a specific set of flags, bypassing the removed *activate* rule type.
2. **tag (Section 3.7.5 of User Manual)** keyword allows us to log all traffic in the session which follows the packet triggered the rule. That is, after the rule trigger all packets will be written to the log until the session is terminated or until it reaches the limit of the *count* option.

These two things make it possible to completely dispense with the old inflexible activate/dynamic rule types.